# D3.js - merge two adjacency matrices in ones with D3/JS

Tags: javascript, d3.js, adjacency-matrix

I want to merge 2 adjacency matrices in ones with d3.js. Just as example:

Matrix 1:

```
{
    "nodes":[
        {
            "id": a,
            "year": 1
        },{
            "id": b,
            "year": 1
        },
        {
            "id": c,
            "year": 1
        }
    ],
    "links":[
        {
            "source": a,
            "target": b
        },
        {
            "source": a,
            "target": c
        }
    ]
}
```

Matrix 2:

```
{
    "nodes":[
        {
            "id": a,
            "year": 2
        },{
            "id": b,
            "year": 2
        },
        {
            "id": d,
            "year": 2
        }
    ],
    "links":[
        {
            "source": a,
            "target": b
        },
        {
            "source": a,
            "target": d
        }
    ]
}
```

as you can see, some IDs appear in both matrices, like a and b. And I want to merge this cell in both matrices in ones and change the color of this cell.
can someone give me some ideas how to solve this issue?

The result must be something like this:

```
{
    "nodes":[
        {
            "id": a,
            "year": 3
        },{
            "id": b,
            "year": 3
        },
        {
            "id": c,
            "year": 1
        },
                {
            "id": d,
            "year": 2
        }
    ],
    "links":[
        {
            "source": a,
            "target": b
        },
        {
            "source": a,
            "target": c
        },
        {
            "source": a,
            "target": d
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Post the expected resulting object to have a clear understanding of what exactly you want to achieve.

Comment: Thank you for your tip! I added the result array to my question.

Comment: `target` is not missing. At some cells there are no any relation between the ids.

Comment: Your expected output does not have `links` property from either of input objects is it done on purpose (then, what's decision logic here?) or by mistake?

Comment: oh sorry, I forgot them. I added them now to my result object.

Comment: check out my updated answer, does it work for you now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, as I understood, what you need to do (merge and highlight duplicate nodes, based on duplicate adjacency, not `id`), you may go like that:

- walk through combined array of `links` to find out unique/duplicate entries (considering reverse `source`/`target` as well)
- walk through combined array of `nodes` and mark with `year:3` those nodes that belong to duplicating links
- build up resulting object of `links` and `nodes`

```js
const m1 = {"nodes":[{"id":'a',"year":1},{"id":'b',"year":1},{"id":'c',"year":1}],"links":[{"source":'a',"target":'b'},{"source":'a',"target":'c'}]},
      m2 = {"nodes":[{"id":'a',"year":2},{"id":'b',"year":2},{"id":'d',"year":2}],"links":[{"source":'a',"target":'b'},{"source":'a',"target":'d'}]},
      
      links = [...m1.links, ...m2.links].reduce((r,l) => {
        const dup = r.find(({source:s, target: t}) => 
          (s == l.source && t == l.target) || 
          (s == l.target && t == l.source))
        dup ? dup.dup = true : r.push(l)
        return r
      }, []),
      
      nodes = [...m1.nodes, ...m2.nodes].reduce((r,n) => {
        const dupL = links.find(l => 
          l.dup && (l.source == n.id || l.target == n.id)),
              dupN = r.find(({id}) => id == n.id)
        !dupN && r.push({...n, ...(dupL && {year: 3})})
        return r
      }, []),
      
      mergedMatrix = {links:links.map(({dup,...rest}) => rest),nodes}
     
console.log(mergedMatrix)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;}
```